# Custom university thesis .cls and minitoc compatibility

Tags: document-classes, minitoc

I suspect that the custom university thesis class which is linked to below  might include something prohibiting implementation of a basic `minitoc` call.

The `.cls` can be found [here](https://projects.cs.dal.ca/dalthesis/dalthesis.cls)

The code made available at this url also includes an mwe for employing the `.cls`.  I very quickly inserted the commands: `\usepackage{minitoc}` (placed in the usual spot), `\dominitoc` (placed before where I think `\tableofcontents` will be called) and `\minitoc` (placed after a `\chapter{}` call) as suggested by the `minitoc` documentation.

I don't observe a minitoc.  I am compiling with PdfLaTeX.

I recognize that the thesis class is designed to achieve standard formatting and that `minitoc`'s may be unwanted.  I see it's implementation as useful for structuring the document and easy enough to disable.

```
% simple.tex -- a very simple thesis document for demonstrating %   dalthesis.cls class file \documentclass[12pt]{dalthesis}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\title{The title} \author{Noah Body}

% The following degrees are included in the current dalthesis.cls % class file: \mcs  % options are \mcs, \macs, \mec, \mhi, \phd, and \bcshon

% If you degree is not included, you can set several options manually. % The following example shows the parameters for the \mcs degree. % However, if you need to set these parameters manually, please check % the correct names with the Faculty of Graduate Studies, and let the % maintainer of this class file know (Vlado Keselj, vlado@cs.dal.ca). % MCS Example:

\degree{Doctor of Mixology} %\degreeinitial{M.C.Sc.} \faculty{Science} \dept{Contemporary Home Economics}

% Month and Year of Defence \defencemonth{June}\defenceyear{2013}

\dedicate{Optionally, the thesis can be dedicated to someone, and the  student can enter the dedication content here.}

% This sample thesis contains no tables nor figures, so there is no % need to include lists of tables and figures in the front matter: \nolistoftables \nolistoffigures

\dominitoc

\frontmatter

\begin{abstract} This is a test document. \end{abstract}

\begin{acknowledgements} Thanks to all the little people who make me look tall. \end{acknowledgements}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

Get it done!  Use reference material by Lamport~\cite{latex-by-lamport} or Gooses, Mittelback, and Samarin~\cite{latex-companion}.

\chapter{Doing It}

\minitoc

\section{Getting Ready}

Get all the parts that I need.  I can throw in a whole pile of terms like preparation, methodology, forethought, and analysis as examples for me to use in the future.

\section{Next Step}

Do it!

Of course, you have to have pictures to show how you did it to make people understand things better.

\chapter{Conclusion}

Did it!

\bibliographystyle{plain} \bibliography{simple}

\end{document}
```

I note that I do see a file called `mwe.mtc4` the content of which looks like:

```
{\reset@font\mtcSfont\mtc@string\contentsline{section}{\noexpand \leavevmode \numberline {2.1}Getting Ready}{\reset@font\mtcSfont 2}}
{\reset@font\mtcSfont\mtc@string\contentsline{section}{\noexpand \leavevmode \numberline {2.2}Next Step}{\reset@font\mtcSfont 2}}
```

A series of these files are being generated: `mwe.mtc`, `mwe.mtc0`, `mwe.mtc1`, `mwe.mtc2`, `mwe.mtc3`, `mwe.mtc4`, `mwe.mtc5` most of which have size 0 KB, while only `mwe.mtc4` has content.  Encouraging, but I don't understand why the minitoc does not appear after the chapter call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This is most likely not a complete solution. Both `dalthesis` and `minitoc` redefine a lot of internal commands related to chapters, formatting of the various lists etc. I tried to fix at least the most obvious problems in your example.*

The main problem with `dalthesis` and `minitoc` is that the minitoc numbering gets out of sync because both files redefine or patch `\chapter` or its internal macros. So the first step is to correctly chain all the patched commands together. (`minitoc` detects redefinitions and issues a warning which has to be suppressed too.)

As `minitoc` creates `.mtc*` files based on `\contentsline` entries in the `.toc` file, the numbering is still wrong when a chapter appears in the ToC but isn't numbered. The reading process for all minitoc files then doesn't find the correct file. This is why you don't get a minitoc for chapter 2, because the contents is written to the `.mtc4` file. To adjust the numbering for starred chapters, `minitoc` provides a `\chapterbegin` command which is written to the `.toc` file to signal that the minitoc counter should be decremented. However, the current implementation doesn't work on its own, so it needs a fix too.

The final step is to write this `\chapterbegin` marker to the `.toc` file whenever a starred chapter occurs together with a ToC entry. This happens in `dalthesis` in the `\nonumchapter`, `\prefacesection` and `\frontmatter` macros. In the latter the writing has to go to the `.lot` and `.lof` files, respectively.

With all the patches applied the numbering seems to correctly work with `\chapter`, `\chapter*`, the list of tables and figures, and the bibliography if it occurs last in the document.

Full updated example (relevant changes occur only in the preamble):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{dalthesis}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bbl}
  \begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem[1]{latex-by-lamport}\LaTeX\ by Lamport
  \bibitem[2]{latex-companion}\LaTeX\ companion
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\makeatletter

% Link redefinitions for normal chapters
\let\sv@chapter\dal@chapter
\def\dal@chapter[#1]#2{%
    \stepcounter{mtc}%
    \sv@chapter[{#1}]{#2}\relax%
    \addcontentsline{lof}{xchapter}{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{lot}{xchapter}{#1}%
    \ignorespaces
}

% Link redefinitions for starred chapters
\let\orig@schapter\mtc@schapter
\let\mtc@schapter\dal@schapter
% TODO: Is this @@@ thing ever used?
\def\dal@schapter{\addtocontents{@@@}{\protect\chapterbegin}\mtc@schapter}
\let\@schapter\orig@schapter

% To suppress redefinition warning
\let\mtc@hints@@schapter\@schapter

% Marker to adjust minitoc numbering in .toc file
\def\chapterbegin{\chapterbegin@}
\let\chapterbegin@\relax

% Correct minitoc numbering for starred chapters with ToC entry
\def\nonumchapter#1{%
    \chapter*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\chapterbegin}%
}
\def\prefacesection#1{%
    \chapter*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\chapterbegin}%
}

% Correct minitoc numbering for LoT/LoF
\let\orig@frontmatter\frontmatter
\def\frontmatter{%
    \orig@frontmatter
    \ifdal@tables@page
        \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\protect\protect\chapterbegin}}%
    \fi
    \ifdal@figures@page
        \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\protect\protect\chapterbegin}}%
    \fi
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{The title} \author{Noah Body}

% The following degrees are included in the current dalthesis.cls % class file: \mcs  % options are \mcs, \macs, \mec, \mhi, \phd, and \bcshon

% If you degree is not included, you can set several options manually. % The following example shows the parameters for the \mcs degree. % However, if you need to set these parameters manually, please check % the correct names with the Faculty of Graduate Studies, and let the % maintainer of this class file know (Vlado Keselj, vlado@cs.dal.ca). % MCS Example:

\degree{Doctor of Mixology} %\degreeinitial{M.C.Sc.} \faculty{Science} \dept{Contemporary Home Economics}

% Month and Year of Defence
\defencemonth{June}\defenceyear{2013}

\dedicate{Optionally, the thesis can be dedicated to someone, and the  student can enter the dedication content here.}

% This sample thesis contains no tables nor figures, so there is no % need to include lists of tables and figures in the front matter:
%\nolistoftables \nolistoffigures

\dominitoc

\frontmatter

\begin{abstract} This is a test document. \end{abstract}

\begin{acknowledgements} Thanks to all the little people who make me look tall. \end{acknowledgements}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

Get it done!  Use reference material by Lamport~\cite{latex-by-lamport} or Gooses, Mittelback, and Samarin~\cite{latex-companion}.

\chapter{Doing It}

\minitoc

\section{Getting Ready}

Get all the parts that I need.  I can throw in a whole pile of terms like preparation, methodology, forethought, and analysis as examples for me to use in the future.

\section{Next Step}

Do it!

Of course, you have to have pictures to show how you did it to make people understand things better.

\chapter{Conclusion}

Did it!

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Comment: I'm grateful for this fix.  When deployed in a non-mwe document, it works well as far as I can tell.